# toss an object in tossed direction

Tags: iphone, object, move

I've been trying to create a function to toss an object using 'touch' and make it go in a straight line with the direction it was tossed in, very close to "paper toss". any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Here are some ideas: 1. Accept some of your previous answers. (See the "How do I ask questions here?" section of http://stackoverflow.com/faq for more info.) 2. Try searching for an existing answer (and then potentially asking this question) on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: been there, done that, ddn't find anything, thus, I posted my question here :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a great tutorial on how to build this sort of code:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/25791/rotating-turrets-how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-2

It will give you the straight line. You would have to add a scaling function if you need depth. Paper Toss will vary to this based on the path drawn - they use a bezier curve.

Better late than never.
Cheers.